# Передать в консоль контекст вызова функции

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, назовем ее `bottomLevel()` она должна передавать в консоль контекст вызова, а точнее название функции, которая ее вызвала, назовем ее `topLevel()`.

Как это сделать?

```js
function bottomLevel() {
  funcName = this.name
  console.log("funcName =", this.name);
  // this в данном  контексте это window и консоль не передает никакого имени.
}

function topLevel() {
  bottomLevel();
}

topLevel();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте это:

Так Вы узнаете что вызвало функцию `bottomLevel()`

```
function bottomLevel() {
  alert("caller is " + bottomLevel.caller.name);
}

function topLevel() {
  bottomLevel();
}

topLevel();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function bottomLevel() {
  funcName = arguments.callee.caller.name
  console.log("funcName =", funcName);
  // this в данном  контексте это window и консоль не передает никакого имени.
}

function topLevel() {
  bottomLevel();
}

topLevel();
```

Comment: Но ведь данное решение не поддерживается/не рекомендуется в современном `javascript`, поправьте, если ошибаюсь.

Comment: @meine, `caller` и `callee` не поддерживаются в strict mode, поэтому в общем случае оба ответа не совсем корректны.

Answer (score 0):

Console.trace()

[MDN: Console.trace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Console/trace)